# working website on cd rom disc

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, cd-rom

General Question : 
A website that was built under Wamp server using phpmyadmin and mysql at my local host -  How Can I place it in a cdrom drive so I can take the website and edit it from every where.
I thought of installing xampp on the cdrom drive. Would that work?

Comment: I can't use disk on key. only cdrom disc. Thank's!

Comment: You want to be able to edit a website … written on a CD ROM … when ROM means Read Only Memory?!

Comment: Seems like you need a portable website with you. Yes, you can copy Xampp files on CD ROM but before copying them to CD, make sure you update path (eg, from C drive to E Drive may be)  and it will definitely work. CD ROM can be written only once, so you won't be able to update any files at later stage. If you are using a Rewritable CD, then it can be done but this process is not efficient as it will take alot of time to write a CD. My suggestion is to use a PenDrive.

Comment: I’m not sure that you will be able to run XAMPP from CD ROM. There are some discussions around, but they are quite old, but you should search form them to see how it would be done. You certainly won’t be able to save back to the CD. If you plan to use a laptop, why not install it there? Also, I assume you are running Windows?

Comment: @Quentin, that's exactly my problem. I can't use usb.

Comment: @Manngo, Yes, I'm running windows.

Comment: @Toto88 If you are limited to not using USB (why?) and you need something portable, you should consider the cloud options.

Comment: I've found this : http://lamppix.tinowagner.com/en/about/packages/ 
It will work?

Comment: look for CD autorun bat-script.